# jquery simulate click on html anchor tag on galaxy tablet

Tags: android, jquery, anchor

i readly know/read a lot of questions/answer about this suject but my problem is on **the navigator of tablet Galaxy 2**

[here is my work on http://jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/dsea/ruWB8/20/)

I tried all solutions but it doesn't work on navigator Galaxy 2: the file isn't automatically downloaded.
When i click on this link or type url on adresse bar => it works
thanks a lot
best regards

javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//$('#fileHrefId')[0].click();
//window.location.href=$('#fileHrefId').attr('href');
document.location.href=$('#fileHrefId').attr('href');
//$('#fileHrefId').click();
//$('#fileHrefId').trigger('click')
```

})

html

```
<a id=fileHrefId href="http://xyz?file=myfile.txt">myfile.txt</a>
```

Comment: please post your html here too.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want `touchend`:

```
$('#yourSelector').trigger('touchend');
```

Also, you may want to check out [hammer.js](http://eightmedia.github.io/hammer.js/) for additional functionality

Comment: i will try it at home with galaxy tablet. Now i'm at office: tested with my iphone: it doesn't work

Comment: $('#fileHrefId').trigger('touchend'); doesn't work :(